# NodeJS, MongoDB, Aggregation function with $lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to build a tree via MongoDB; I am using [$lookup][1] to join my collection with itself:

```js
  db.collection('Category').aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "Category",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "parentCategory",
        as: "subcategory"
    }

  }],callback)
```

Almost everything works fine, but in case when I join collection with itself (not with different collection), child records are displayed in the main tree too.

My output:

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "57d15c8b88f66c1ba43f4c1a",
        "name": "OLOLOLO",
        "parentCategory": null,
        "subcategory": [
            {
            "_id": "57d15cc488f66c1ba43f4c1b",
            "name": "OLOLOLO2",
            "parentCategory": "57d15c8b88f66c1ba43f4c1a"
            },
            {
            "_id": "57d15cc988f66c1ba43f4c1c",
            "name": "OLOLOLO3",
            "parentCategory": "57d15c8b88f66c1ba43f4c1a"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "57d15cc488f66c1ba43f4c1b",
        "name": "OLOLOLO2",
        "parentCategory": "57d15c8b88f66c1ba43f4c1a",
        "subcategory": []
    },
    {
        "_id": "57d15cc988f66c1ba43f4c1c",
        "name": "OLOLOLO3",
        "parentCategory": "57d15c8b88f66c1ba43f4c1a",
        "subcategory": []
    }
]
```

As you can see, my data with names OLOLOLO2 and OLOLOLO3 are duplicated.

Are there any possibility to fix it via defined methods, or I have to write my own sort method ?

I need to get such result:

```
[
{
    "_id": "57d15c8b88f66c1ba43f4c1a",
    "name": "OLOLOLO",
    "parentCategory": null,
    "subcategory": [
        {
        "_id": "57d15cc488f66c1ba43f4c1b",
        "name": "OLOLOLO2",
        "parentCategory": "57d15c8b88f66c1ba43f4c1a"
        },
        {
        "_id": "57d15cc988f66c1ba43f4c1c",
        "name": "OLOLOLO3",
        "parentCategory": "57d15c8b88f66c1ba43f4c1a"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I did it via custom sorting :

```
  db.collection('Category').aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "Category",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "parentCategory",
        as: "subcategory"
    }

  }],function(err,result){
      if(err) return callback(err);
      var sortedData = [];
      result.forEach(function(category){
        if(!category.parentCategory) return sortedData.push(category);
      });
      callback(null,sortedData);
    }
  )
```

So in sortedData I have final result. But it would be nice to do it via default method if this is possible

Comment: Hi user2414751 - can you show us an example of the output you want to get from your query?

Comment: I edited my question and putted an example there